# Combining reducers best practices

Tags: redux, react-router

In redux,

If an action creator wants to modify two combined reducer states.
Then, what is it better:

1. The action creator dispatches two action types?
2. The action creator dispatches one action type and the two reducers listen to that action?
3. When I cannot subscribe actions to a reducer, (i.e. the reducer of react router) the only solution that I have is to dispatch my reducer action and then to dispatch the result of an action creator (i.e. react router's push or replace) as a side effect using a thunk or saga

What do you guys think?

Comment: The phrase "two states" is confusing. A store only has one state. Do you mean two properties of the state tree? Or does your app have two stores?

Comment: I usually go with #2 unless it will be very confusing to reason about later.  However, this *could* be a sign that you haven't divided the reducers up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is a viable approach.  The Redux FAQ addresses this under ["Should I dispatch multiple actions in a row from one action creator?"](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#should-i-dispatch-multiple-actions-in-a-row-from-one-action-creator):

> In general, ask if these actions are related but independent, or should actually be represented as one action. Do what makes sense for your own situation but try to balance the readability of reducers with readability of the action log. For example, an action that includes the whole new state tree would make your reducer a one-liner, but the downside is now you have no history of why the changes are happening, so debugging gets really difficult. On the other hand, if you emit actions in a loop to keep them granular, it's a sign that you might want to introduce a new action type that is handled in a different way.

I also addressed the topic in my article [Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks, Sagas, Abstraction, and Reusability](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/).